# identifier inside javascript to replace a word

Tags: javascript

I am very new to JavaScript; I have the following code;

```
    var ops=[
        '-r', '17',
        '-i','-',
        '-strict', '-2',
        '-b:v', '1M',
        '-g', '60',
        '-hls_time', '2',
        '-hls_list_size', '0',
        '/var/www/html/streams/output.m3u8'
    ];
```

I would like to replace the file name `output` with a identifier  `socket._streamKey` what would the syntax look like to replace the word with the identifier. Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Is the file name always `output`? Is the identifier always `socket._streamKey`?

Comment: i want the file name to be the `socket._streamKey.m3u8` and not `output` and yeah the identifier is always the same if i was to do this in PHP it would look like this `echo '/var/www/html/streams/' . $streamKey . '.m3u8';` if that helps at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is an alternative:

```
ops = ops.map(o => o.replace('output', 'socket._streamKey'))
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it is to loop through the array, find an entry that contains the word 'output', and if there is a match then replace output with socket._streamKey.

```
var ops=[
    '-r', '17',
    '-i','-',
    '-strict', '-2',
    '-b:v', '1M',
    '-g', '60',
    '-hls_time', '2',
    '-hls_list_size', '0',
    '/var/www/html/streams/output.m3u8'
];

for (var i = 0; i < ops.length; i++)
 if (ops[i].includes('output'))
    ops[i] = ops[i].replace('output','socket._streamKey');
```

Comment: The `if` statement is not necessary.